# pyodbc.Error: ('IM001', '[IM001] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver does not support this function (0) (SQLNumParams)')

Tags: python, ms-access, odbc, unixodbc

I have Using pyodbc connection for python 2.7 with MS Access in Ubuntu 16.04

This Query working fine **SELECT LogDate  FROM DeviceLogs**. but i will filter the data using **date condition** Query as **SELECT LogDate  FROM DeviceLogs WHERE  UserId =? and LogDate >= ?**.

[This Issue i have already told and post following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41327773/how-to-retrieving-values-where-cause-using-date-time-value-from-a-microsoft-acce)

**Code:**

```
from_date = cur.fetchone()
from_date = from_date[0] - timedelta(0,19800)
date_input = '#' + str(from_date) + ' 06:26:46#'
print date_input,"AAAAAAAA"
from_date = str(from_date) + ' 00:00:00'
from_date = datetime.strptime(from_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print from_date,"BBBBBBBBb"

sql="SELECT LogDate  FROM DeviceLogs WHERE  UserId =? and LogDate >= ? "
params = datetime(2016, 12, 01)
csr.execute(sql, '27797',params)
att_records = csr.fetchall()
print att_records,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
```

**ERROR Details below following**

```
    #2016-12-19 06:26:46# AAAAAAAA
2016-12-19 00:00:00 BBBBBBBBb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "val.py", line 38, in <module>
    csr.execute(sql, '27797',params)
pyodbc.Error: ('IM001', '[IM001] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver does not support this function (0) (SQLNumParams)')
```

Comment: Try `params = ('27797', datetime(2016, 12, 01))` followed by `csr.execute(sql, params)`

Comment: I try this. but not working Thanks.

Comment: Per @GordThompson's suggestion,  what does not work, specifically exceptions/errors?

Comment: Curious, too, how are you connecting to MS Access? Which driver? MS Access is strictly a Windows software and cannot be run natively on Linux/Mac.

Comment: Could be an issue of having python 2.7 and pyodbc working together. I had the same problem but by using python 3.5 it goes away.